# vi readline support for jruby's irb

Tags: ruby, jruby, vi, readline

I recently started using jruby. In normal ruby's irb, I get vi readline support due to the .editrc file

.editrc file

bind -v

But jruby doesn't seem to use that file, and doesn't get the vi readline from the .inuptrc file either.

Is there a way to get vi readline support in jirb?

Answer (score 3):

JRuby doesn't use libedit or readline, so those files are not read.

Furthermore, JRuby does not support vi editing mode.

```
irb(main):001:0> Readline.vi_editing_mode?
NotImplementedError: vi_editing_mode?() function is unimplemented on this machine
    from org/jruby/ext/Readline.java:358:in `basic_quote_characters'
    from (irb):1:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1022:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1338:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1131:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1131:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/jruby/bin/jirb:13:in `(root)'
```

Admittedly, JRuby's Readline support has a lot to be desired.